# Upstart service is not starting in ubuntu

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, service, upstart

I have a following configuration in app.conf, I have the www-data user, and the app is in ~/app directory. The directory of node is fine and the cluster is also fine. I have also tried it without the bin/cluster.
But my upstart service is not starting? Is there any thing more to do? I am stuck. Every time I run `sudo service app start` it gets stuck in stop/waiting.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
env APP_HOME=~/app/
env NODE_ENV=production
env RUN_AS_USER=www-data

start on (net-device-up
          and local-filesystems
          and runlevel [2345])
stop on runlevel [016]

respawn
respawn limit 5 60

pre-start script
    test -x /usr/local/bin/node || { stop; exit 0; }
    test -x $APP_HOME/bin/cluster || { stop; exit 0; }
    test -e $APP_HOME && test -e $APP_HOME/logs || { stop; exit 0; }
end script

script
    chdir $APP_HOME
    exec /usr/local/bin/node bin/cluster app.js -u $RUN_AS_USER -l logs/app.out -e logs/app.err >> $APP_HOME/logs/upstart.log
end script
```

Comment: Initial thought is that you need to specify specific paths, where as you're passing `bin/cluster` to node executable. Try providing a specific path. As for the arguments where you pass partial paths for logs, that should be fine because a node module will assume its location as a current working directory in most cases.

Comment: Also there is [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) which provides clustering. PM2 has the ability to start itself as a daemon. You launch apps who's process is managed by PM2. PM2 can create its own service(upstart/init.d/etc) where it boots on startup/restart. PM2 offers similar features such as max retries, as well as clustering features like hot reloading which rotates one node process out at a time providing zero down time deployment(if you run multiple processes). It might make more sense to not reinvent the wheel and gain the extra features without investing your own time.

Comment: the clustering file is in the app directory itself and the log files as well. I haven't used PM2 yet, Ill try that instead.

Comment: I think it would save you a lot of time. You seem to handle logging, clustering, and daemonizing yourself, which is already provided by PM2. If you adopt its paradigm you don't have to worry about setting up your environment and you can just leverage something that already exists, and you won't have to worry about maintaining this logic yourself unless you decide to contribute to PM2.